# Proving a Problem involving Fibonacci numbers

Tags: proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I'm working on proving the problem that states

$\text {The sequence}$ {$F_n$} $\text {is defined by the} \ F_1=F_2=1, F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n \ \text  {for} \ n \ge 1.$ $\text {For any natural number m, define} \ v_2(m) \ as$  $v_2(m)=n \ if \ 2^n|m \ and \ 2^{n+1}|m.$ $\text {For all possible positive integer n that satisfy the equation:} $ $$v_2(n!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3...F_n)$$

First, to start out I want to make sure that I'm understanding the problem $$v_2(5!)=v_2(1*1*2*3*5)$$
$$v_2(120)=v_2(30)$$
So am I supposed to see if $2^5|120$ or $2^5|30$

I guess I'm having trouble figuring out what my $m$ is supposed to be. Thanks for any and all the help you can give!

Comment: Is the problem rather to *find* all such $n$?

Comment: Yes it is! I just didn't even know how to start this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $m$ on the left is $120$ and on the right is $30$.  You are supposed to count the factors of $2$ in each and see if they are equal.  As an example $v_2(48)=4$ because $2^4|48$ but $2^5 \not | 48$

Comment: If you used n=4 how did you get $v_2(48)$? because if I use $$v_2(n!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3...F_n)$$ I get $$ v_2(4!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3F_4)$$ Which simplifies to $$v_2(24)=v_2(6)$$ Right? What am I still messing up on? This seems like it should be so simple, but I just can't wrap my brain around it.

Comment: So am I picking $m$ as my variable or $n$ to start out with? because there is no possible value of $n$ that makes either side of $$v_2(n!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3...F_n)=v_2(48)$$ right?

Comment: $v_2$ is a function that can be applied to any natural.  I used $48$ to demonstrate how it works.  $48$ has no relation to the Fibonacci numbers.  In your first comment you have expressed the $n=4$ question properly.  Now note that $v_2(24)=3$ and $v_2(6)=1$, so the equation is not satisfied.  Similarly the equation is not satisfied for $n=5$ as $v_2(120) \neq v_2(24)$.  I think in the original question "For" should be "Find".  One example is $n=6$ because $v_2(6!)=v_2(720)=4,$  the product of the Fibonacci numbers is $240, v_2(240)=4.\ \  n=7$ will work, too.  I don't know about any more.

Comment: Okay, maybe i'm dense, but can you make sure I'm doing it right? I took $n=7$ and got $$v_2(7!)=v_2(1*1*2*3*5*8*13)$$ Which when I simplified it went to $$v_2(5040)=v_2(3120)=4$$ But what am I doing with the $$2^n|m \text and \ 2^{n+1}\m$$ am I showing that both $2^nk=5040$ and $2^nk=3120$ and then that $2^{n+1}k=5040$ and $2^{n+1}=3120$?

Comment: I don't see what you have changed.  For $n=5$ no, you are not supposed to see if $2^5|120$  (it doesn't) or $2^5^30$ (again it doesn't)  You are supposed to find the highest power of $2$ which divides into $120$ (which is $3$) and into $30$ (which is $1$).  The fact that they are not equal says $5$ does not satisfy the relation.  I showed you above that $6$ does satisfy it and claimed that $7$ does while $8$ does not.  Can you check $7$ and $8$, showing your work?  There is also one smaller value that works.

Comment: So I started with $n=7$ and got $$v_2(7!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3F_4F_5F_6F_7)$$ Which is $$v_2(5040)=v_2(3120)$$ So then I looked at $$v_2(5040) \ \text {and got that} \ 5040=2*2*2*2*315 \ \text so \ v_2(5040)=4$$ Then I looked at $$v_2(3120) \ \text {and got that} \ 3120=2*2*2*2*195 \ \text so \ v_2(3120)=4$$ So that means that $v_2(5040)=v_2(3120)$ So that means that one answer that satisfies this equation is $n=7$ right? or is it $n=4$ because that was the power of 2 in both of them?

Comment: Then I tried with $n=8$ and got $$v_2(8!)=v_2(F_1F_2F_3F_4F_5F_6F_7F_8)$$ Which is $$v_2(40320)=v_2(65520)$$ So then I looked at $$v_2(40320) \ \text {and got that} \ 40320=2*2*2*2*2*2*2*315 \ \text so \ v_2(40320)=7$$ Then I looked at $$v_2(65520) \ \text {and got that} \ 65520=2*2*2*2*4095 \ \text so \ v_2(65520)=4$$ So that means that $v_2(40320)\neq v_2(65520)$

Comment: Yes, you are doing this correctly.  Now we know $n=6$ and $7$ work.  When you go from $n!$ to $n+1$ factorial, you add as many factors of $2$ as there are in $n+1$  When you add one more Fibonacci number to the list you add as many factors of $2$ as are in the new Fibonacci number.  That is how I knew that $7$ works from knowing that $6$ works.  $7$ has no factors of $2$ and neither does $F_7=13$  I suspect that one can prove that there are a finite number of cases that work because $2$'s become too plentiful in $n!$, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting too much if you stay with the original definition
given for any natural number m;that is v2(m) = n if 2^n and 2^(n+1) divide m.
you then consider those integers satisfying v2(n!) = v2((F_1)(F_2).....(F_n)).
In your example,we have v2(5!) = v2(120) = 2 since by definition 2^2|120 and
2^3|120,but no higher power of 2.For the right hand side,which involves the
product of the first 5 Fibonacci numbers =30, we have by your definition that
v2(30) = 0 since 2^0|30, 2^1|30,but no higher value of 2^k will work.Offhand,
I see no eason that a factorial and product of Fibonacci numbers should have
the same value of v2.       Edwin Gray